# py2exe with import pyfits cause error

Tags: python, py2exe, pyfits

When do py2exe in py-file with import pyfits, it caused an error.

How to avoid this error?

I prepare test.py and test_setup.py(for py2exe), which are shown below.

test.py is simple program to show data of fitsfile specified by the argument.

- OS : Windows7 64bit
- python : 2.7
- pyfits : 3.3
- numpy : 1.9.2

**on cmd.exe:**

```
\python test_setup.py py2exe
```

=> success

```
\python test.py test.fits
[[[574 574 579 ..., 579 585 581]
  [574 582 583 ..., 582 579 577]
  [581 583 578 ..., 572 580 580]
  ...,
  [584 585 580 ..., 584 582 579]
  [585 583 582 ..., 586 575 578]
  [584 580 583 ..., 585 585 589]]]
```

=> success

```
\dist\test.exe test.fits
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    import pyfits
  File "pyfits\__init__.pyo", line 11, in <module>
  File "pyfits\core.pyo", line 42, in <module>
  File "pyfits\convenience.pyo", line 62, in <module>
  File "pyfits\hdu\__init__.pyo", line 2, in <module>
  File "pyfits\hdu\compressed.pyo", line 21, in <module>
  File "pyfits\hdu\table.pyo", line 646, in <module>
  File "pyfits\hdu\table.pyo", line 909, in BinTableHDU
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

=> error

---

**test.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import pyfits

def showfits(path):
    hdulist = pyfits.open(path)
    imgs = hdulist[0].data
    hdulist.close()
    print imgs

if __name__ == "__main__":
    showfits(sys.argv[1])
```

---

**test_setup.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

option = {
    "compressed"    :    1    ,
    "optimize"      :    2    ,
    "bundle_files"  :    3    
}

setup(
    options = {
        "py2exe"    :    option
    },

    console = [
        {
            "script"   :    "test.py"
        }
    ],
    zipfile = None
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [line it's crashing on](https://github.com/spacetelescope/PyFITS/blob/v3.3.0/lib/pyfits/hdu/table.py#L909):

```
dump.__doc__ += _tdump_file_format.replace('\n', '\n        ')
```

it seems that pyfits is doing some class-level docstring manipulation.  This could reasonably be considered a bug, since it can't always be assumed that a method's `__doc__` will be a string, as in in the case of using optimized compilation (as you are) which, among other things, strips out all docstrings.

I think the simplest workarounds would be either to disable optimization, at least for now, or patch pyfits to remove that line and any similar to it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your good advice. I set optimize option to 0(no optimization) and can solve this problem!

Comment: Incidentally, there is a patch for this now in astropy: https://github.com/astropy/astropy/pull/3923  Since `astropy.io.fits` is `pyfits`, the relevant parts of this patch should also make their way into `pyfits`.